# Is it possible to clone a git repo when given "<IP Address>:/<Path to App> with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

What i have is:

```
a.b.c.d:/x/www/app
```

Now if i issue the command:

git clone a.b.c.d:/x/www/app /home/user

i am prompted for my LDAP Password and then clone the app successfully.

But when i use the same with Jenkins, Jenkins gives error:

Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h a.b.c.d:/x/www/app HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I am using Jenkins version 1.500 and Git plugin version 1.1.26

ERROR:

```
Using strategy: Default
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git:///$GIT_USER@a.b.c.d:/var/www/app
git --version
git version 1.7.9.5
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git:///$GIT_USER@a.b.c.d:/var/www/app
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone git:///$GIT_USER@a.b.c.d:/var/www/app
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:273)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1044)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:986)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2348)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git clone --progress -o origin git:///$GIT_USER@a.b.c.d:/var/www/app /home/user/workspace/app" returned status code 128:
stdout: Cloning into '/home/user/workspace/app'...

stderr: fatal: unable to connect to :
: Name or service not known


    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:897)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.access$000(GitAPI.java:42)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:269)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI$1.invoke(GitAPI.java:248)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:248)
    ... 12 more
Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
FATAL: Could not clone
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1056)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:986)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2348)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: How is Jenkin's git authentication configured?

Comment: @AndrewMyers
using export GIT_USER=myUser:myPassword, from Jenkins --> Configure system --> Environment variables

Comment: when i use git://.... ( see Question ) I have added stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git:// protocol does not use authentication.

If you want to use the protocol, you need to start git-daemon on your server-side repository.

If ssh with username/key based authentication is what you wanted, use ssh://$USER/path instead.

Comment: Would just like to add that the ssh://<IP Address>/path works if the ssh key is exchanged , i.e append the public key for the user you use while setting up your slave

Answer (score 0):

you can use git+ssh://mylogin@mygithost:/var/git/race.git

if you use ssh, you can edit or create in jenkins user home dir : ~/.ssh/config to store a ssh key

```
Host mygithost
        HostName 192.168.130.43
        User mylogin
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/.id_rsa
```

with a ssh key, you can add the public key on the git server (~/.ssh/authorized_keys) to prevent the password auth...